# Instant Messaging End-to-End

Tags: rsa, instant-messaging, secure-coding, forward-secrecy

I plan to create an application for secure instant messaging, now I don't know whether or not I want to implement the encryption by myself. This project is also mainly for educational purpose so I wouldn't mind a bit of extra work.

My 'vision' is that every device that registers for my service generates a RSA-2048 keypair.
The public key is then stored at the server and exchanged when the device (user) is being added as 'friend'.

When a session is created I would perform a ECDH key exchange for Perfect Forward Secrecy and then agree to a AES-256 symmetric key. The server stores this AES key in a database together with a SHA-1 hash for identifying it at future session reconnects until a new key is negotiated. Not to forget a nonce against replay attacks.

Is there a lot more I would have to think about when creating a secure protocol?

Thanks in advance,
conFusion

Comment: Have you looked into "Off The Record (OTR)"?  
https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/

Comment: Yea i'm trying it out right now, but i'd prefer doing it all by myself for some reason. But if there are major problems i haven't thought of i'm going for OTR i guess.

Comment: First go read the FAQ about rolling your own encryption, then explain why you don't like TLS/DTLS